# customer live chat widget for ionic app

Tags: widget, ionic3, livechat, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I have a simple ionic tab application with three tabs. Structure of which is as follows :

```
>TabsPage
  >HomePage
  >AboutPage
  >ContactPage
```

I want to have a customer live chat feature for which currently I am trying to use PureChat.

In order to use PureChat in my app, I have to copy paste a small script in my app, and I'm currently pasting the PureChat script in my index.html.

## 1. Having the script in  index.html is causing the PureChat Hello button to appear on all the pages in my app but I want that button to appear only on my ContactPage.

**Please suggest how to have that button appear only on my contact page.**

Answer (score 1):

I've got this working on my ionic 3 app - mine is a little different.

I've got a link on the menu to open the live chat window - however your problem is very similar.... I didn't want to use the standard purechat button i needed a link on a menu link instead.
I added widget with the 'custom button' selected in PureChat

Then get it to work I added the embed code into the

On my menu i added:

```
<a (click)="openLiveChat()" menuClose class="menulink">Open Live Chat</a>
```

Then in my app.component.ts I added this function:

```
openLiveChat(){
    console.log("OpenLiveChat has been clicked");
    let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementsByClassName('purechat-collapsed-image')[0] as HTMLElement;
    element.click();
 }
```

So technically the chat is on every page - but its hidden until the openLiveChat() function is called

Answer (score 0):

Inject the script into the contact page

```
export class ContactPage{
  addScript: boolean = false;

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    if (!this.addScript) {
      this.addPureChatScript();
    }
  }

  addPureChatScript() {
    this.addScript = true;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let scripttagElement = document.createElement('script');
      scripttagElement.src = 'location/or/url/of/script';
      scripttagElement.onload = resolve;
      document.body.appendChild(scripttagElement);
    })
  }
}
```